# DevExpress SpinEdit shows 0 for null value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I use MVVM in my project and in the ViewModel I use an int? value:

```
public int? Value1 { get; set;}
```

I have the following SpinEdit in my view:

```
<dxe:SpinEdit Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinValue="1000" MaxValue="2000"
Name="Value1" IsFloatValue="False" NullText="Enter value" AllowNullInput="True" 
NullValue="{x:Null}" MaskType="None" />
```

When I open the view, the NullText shows the correct value but when I enter some value into the SpinEdit and then *set the Value1 to null*, I get a 0 in my SpinEdit. As it has Min and Max value, it is invalid data.

[image]

What should I do to make the 0 value disappear *without the heavy event handler hackings*?

Comment: This is all UI.  Handle it in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<dx:ASPxSpinEdit  ID="spinedit" runat="server" MaxValue="2000" MinValue="1000" NullText="Enter value" AllowNull="true" AllowNullInput="True" NullValue="{x:Null}" MaskType="None"></dx:ASPxSpinEdit>
```